# how to get raw data for a nested key in my replit database python

Tags: python, database, dictionary, replit, replit-database

In the python code below, I am getting the raw data for the key "users" in my database. However I need the raw data only for the key "shares" inside of "users". How would I do this?

Python code to get "users" data:

```
db.get_raw("users")
```

Database:

```
{
  "users": {
    "dylan@dylan.com": {
      "password": 12345,
      "shares": {
        "AAPL": {
          "total_shares": 1,
          "total_cost": 134.51,
          "purchases": [
            {
              "shares": 1,
              "price": 134.51
            }
          ],
          "current_price": "134.51",
          "last_updated": 1671406955.5399585,
          "current_value": 134.51
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do:

```
db["users"]["dylan@dylan.com"].get_raw("shares")
```

```
db.get_raw("users")["dylan@dylan.com"]["shares"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

```
json.loads(db.get_raw("users")).get("dylan@dylan.com").get("shares")
```

Python JSON Decoding: https://www.guru99.com/python-json.html